# Limit CSS style recalculation with webkit animations

Tags: javascript, html, css, webkit, frame-rate

I'm working on a project of mine that uses webkit animations.
It's an HTML project with Javascript ans CSS3.

I tried to run it on Chrome, it works fine but as soon as i try it on a low configuration, it is getting slower. So I activated the Chrome's Timeline and.. Surprise. CSS style is recalculated every 2ms from the very begining !

So my question is, is there a way to limit those to like 40 calculations a second in order to free the CPU a little bit..

There is a bit of the code I'm using to animate all this CPU power waste :

```
.miniSignal1{
opacity: 0;
position: absolute;
top : 50px;
left :51px;
width : 400px;
height: 400px;
background-image: url("../../FEZ_resources/images/losange.png");
background-size: 100%;
background-position:center;
background-repeat: no-repeat;
overflow: visible;
-webkit-animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0, 0, .5, 1);
}       
@-webkit-keyframes rescale1{
    0%  { -webkit-transform : scale( 0 , 0 ); opacity: 1;}
    50%     { opacity: 1;}
    100%        { -webkit-transform : scale( 2.5 , 2.5 ); opacity: 0;}
}
@-webkit-keyframes rescale2{
    0%  { -webkit-transform : scale( 0 , 0 ); opacity: 1;}
    50%     { opacity: 1;}
    100%        { -webkit-transform : scale( 2.5 , 2.5 ); opacity: 0;}
}
```

This piece is launched by the Javascript

```
function windowLoaded(){
    setTimeout("launchSignal()",4000);
}

function launchSignal(){
$(".miniSignal1").css("-webkit-animation-name", '');
$(".miniSignal1").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '');
$(".miniSignal2").css("-webkit-animation-name", '');
$(".miniSignal2").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '');
$(".miniSignal3").css("-webkit-animation-name", '');
$(".miniSignal3").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '');
$(".miniSignal4").css("-webkit-animation-name", '');
$(".miniSignal4").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '');
if(signal){
    signal = false;
    $(".miniSignal1").css("-webkit-animation-name", 'rescale1');
    $(".miniSignal1").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '1.5s');
    $(".miniSignal2").css("-webkit-animation-name", 'rescale21');
    $(".miniSignal2").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '1.5s');
    $(".miniSignal3").css("-webkit-animation-name", 'rescale31');
    $(".miniSignal3").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '1.5s');
    $(".miniSignal4").css("-webkit-animation-name", 'rescale41');
    $(".miniSignal4").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '1.5s');
}else{
    signal = true;
    $(".miniSignal1").css("-webkit-animation-name", 'rescale2');
    $(".miniSignal1").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '1.5s');
    $(".miniSignal2").css("-webkit-animation-name", 'rescale22');
    $(".miniSignal2").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '1.5s');
    $(".miniSignal3").css("-webkit-animation-name", 'rescale32');
    $(".miniSignal3").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '1.5s');
    $(".miniSignal4").css("-webkit-animation-name", 'rescale42');
    $(".miniSignal4").css("-webkit-animation-duration", '1.5s');
}
timedSignalCount();
}
```

Is that all the element.css("",""); that redefines the style every 2ms ?

Comment: What is you [animation-duration](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/animation-duration)?

Comment: I'm stupid, I found what was going on... I set an animation duration to 8462ms cause i wanted something random. Problem is, it was reapeating indefinetly screwing global Webkit animation timer...
yeah thanks, you saw right ^^ it was about animation duration...